# jQuery Uploadify - How to use onComplete?

Tags: jquery, uploadify

I'm using uploadify: http://www.uploadify.com/

And have an onComplete:

```
onComplete: function(response) {
alert(response);
},
```

My server is sendin back album_id... How do I access that in the response?

Thanks

**UPDATING**

```
        onComplete: function(response) {
            jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(response.response);
            alert (jsonObject);
            alert(jsonObject.album_id);
        },
```

both of the alerts don't run?

***UPDATE  2***
RAils code that is sending back the JSON? Maybe this is the issue?

render :json => { :result => 'success', :album_id => 31313113 }

Comment: response right now says [object object]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the onComplete is sending four arguments. So you function should be like this one:

```
onComplete: function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
    alert(response.responseText);
    return false;
},
```

The return false is needed to avoid to trigger the default function.

Comment: Maybe rails isn't sending back the right response? I have it harded coded. Uploadify wants JSON right? render :json => { :result => 'success', :album_id => 31313113 }

Comment: Sorry! you should use `alert(response.responseText)`

Comment: If you returns JSON data then you have to parse. But if you just return the album id as a value then this code works

Answer (score 1):

I believe the response sent back is:

```
 function UploadComplete(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) { }
```

Response would obviously be whatever you're returning.  In my case it was a flickrphotoID because my uploadify script was uploading the file to Flickr then waiting for the ID.

If your response is a json object, then you'll need to parse it out.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above are correct in pointing you towards the onComplete method.  The only thing I have to add, is to ask you to post your entire uploadify call.  The onComplete needs to be built in your call.  It should look like something like this.

```
$('#sampleFile').uploadify({
        'uploader': 'include/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'add_list.php',
        'scriptData': {'mode': 'upload'},
        'fileDataName': 'newUpload',
        'folder': '/work/temp/uploads',
        'cancelImg': 'images/cancel.png',
        'queueID': 'uploadQueue',
        'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
        // A function that triggers when a file upload has completed. The default 
        // function removes the file queue item from the upload queue. The 
        // default function will not trigger if the value of your custom 
        // function returns false.
        // Parameters 
        //    event: The event object.
        //    queueID: The unique identifier of the file that was completed.
        //    fileObj: An object containing details about the file that was selected.
        //    response: The data sent back from the server.
        //    data: Details about the file queue.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

//You have to parse it first as a whole object

jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

//Then access the object property or method after

alert(jsonObject.album_id);